# House of Suns - What does Hesperus scratch onto the wine glass?

Tags: alastair-reynolds

In House of Suns, Hesperus scratches a figure resembling a spoked wheel into a wine glass with his thumbnail. Does this represent the:

Remnants of the supramundane ring around Neume?

or the

> Open stardam around the Andromeda wormhole?

or is it intentionally left ambiguous?

Comment: … or the giant zoo from *Pushing Ice* :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the orbital structure around Neume. Purslane realizes this upon approaching the planet and observing the structure from space:

> ‘Hesperus knew this place,’ Purslane said.
>   [..]
>   ‘His design - the cartwheel. We're looking at it. It's a picture of Neume, from space.’